# SQL Query takes long when many rows

Tags: mysql, performance

Using the query:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM surf_times st
WHERE st.Time = 
    (SELECT MIN(t.Time) 
    FROM surf_times t 
    WHERE t.SteamID = st.SteamID AND t.Map = st.Map) 
        AND st.Map = "surf_milkyway"
ORDER BY st.Time
LIMIT 15
```

Takes 0.15~ seconds with 7 results:

```
Showing rows 0 - 6 (7 total, Query took 0.1650 sec) [Time: 61.76 - 70.05]
```

When running this query on a table that will return 15 results, it suddenly takes 23 seconds

```
Showing rows 0 - 14 (15 total, Query took 23.0710 sec) [Time: 47 - 52.13]
```

"surf_milkyway" has 17 total rows and takes 0.16~ seconds to execute.

"surf_beginner" has 2496 total rows and takes 23~ seconds to execute.

It takes 20+ seconds when the map searched for has many results in the table and takes long to compare and sort them. Is this something wrong with the query or the way the table is indexed etc?

Table is structured as:

```
SteamID - bigint(20)
Name - varchar(255)
Map - varchar(255)
Time - float
Date int(20)
id - int(11) - AUTO_INCREMENT, Primary
```

Comment: A good starting point is to read about MySQLs `explain` feature :-) It helps a lot to understand how the query is processed and optimized internally. Often one can enhance things like column type and indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An uncorellated query will always perform better than a corellated one, but if performance is still poor then we'd really need to see the table CREATE statements and the result of the EXPLAIN...

```
SELECT a.*
FROM surf_times a
Join
(SELECT steamid,map, MIN(Time) min_time
FROM surf_times 
Group by steamid,map) b
On b.steamid = a.steamid
And b.map = a.map
And b.min_time = a.time
    Where a.Map = "surf_milkyway"
ORDER BY a.Time
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: From 23 seconds to 0.0460, I was expecting a small gain, nothing like that! I'm defiantly going to be reading up about correlation

Comment: Ok, now change time to decimal, and index steam_id and map. See if a compound index performs better or worse than individual ones

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following indexes will improve performance:

```
INDEX(Steamid, Map, Time),
INDEX(Map, Time)
```